# SQL select where multiple condition by same id from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Please help me, I have a table like below and I want to get data by id with status 'sent' and ' ' only and not with status 'delivered'.

| message_thread_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 229 |  |
| 229 | delivered |
| 229 | sent |
| 229 | delivered |
| 229 | delivered |
| 240 | sent |
| 240 | sent |
| 1044 |  |
| 1044 |  |
| 1044 |  |
| 1068 | delivered |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM mytable a WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 FROM mytable b 
   WHERE a.message_thread_id = b.message_thread_id
   AND status = 'delivered'
)
```

Comment: Wow.. thanks for the answer it's worked 

Comment: you are welcome.